# php.ini error_reporting recommended production value would show notices?

Tags: php, configuration, server

On a server there is still PHP 5.3.3 installed. The php.ini contains the following:

```
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
;   E_ALL | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

I am wondering if the current configuration `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` which is recommended for production environments would show notices? I think I would - but I think it does not make sense for a production system to show notices.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wonder why all errors are reported to everyone. But this does not depend on error_reporting only. The missing thing is to check the value of display_errors in the php.ini.